# Opposite phrase of "close the distance"

Tags: phrase-requests, antonyms

What would be an appropriate opposite phrase for "close the distance".

Example:

> The rabbit was fast. With every leap, the rabbit {{ grew the distance }} between it and the hunter.

Comment: The fixed expression 'increased/extended its lead [over]' is often used, but rarely outside obvious competitions.

Answer (score 3):

One common way would be to say 'widened the gap'.

> The rabbit was fast. With every leap, the rabbit *widened the gap* between it and the hunter.